# Using a string stored in a variable as a name for another variable

Tags: javascript

I want to concatenate a string passed as argument with another word and then use it as a variable name for an array. Is this allowed?

```
function getFromSomewhere(arg1) {

string newName = arg1 + "sampleWord";

var (use NewName here) = [];

}
```

Comment: nice idea, what would you do after you got a new (local) variable?

Comment: code above was just an example, but originally this is what I have in mind, argument is an array of strings, ["apple", "banana", "grapes"], then I'll do array for each of them called applePrices, bananaPrices, grapePrices, then fill them in with prices from a csv file and then display them on a table

Comment: please add you want to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. But no, you dont want to do that. Dynamic variable names are always a sign, that you should use an object instead. In this case i think you could simply map your array of strings to an array of objects:

```
 function namesToObj(arr){
   return arr.map( name => ({
    name,
    price:10
   }));
}

 namesToObj(["banana","tomato"])
 /*results in
 [{name:"banana",price:10},{name:"tomato",price:10}]
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

Not allowed, unfortunately. Variable names, such as *newName*, that we see are rid of at compilation time for optimization. Your machine will have no use for it's name *newName* during runtime, which is when you're trying to assign the name to it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) with the wanted fruits as key for the array, like in the example.

The object is easy to access and to maintain.

```js
var array = ["apple", "banana", "grapes"],
    prices = {};
    
array.forEach(function (k) {
    prices[k] = [];
});

prices.apple.push(1, 10, 3);

console.log(prices.apple[2]);
console.log(prices);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `newName` as the name of a property

```
function getFromSomewhere(arg1) {

    var myVariableNamedAtRuntime = [];


    string newName = arg1 + "sampleWord";

    myVariableNamedAtRuntime[newName] = [];

}
```

and then access the array as ...

```
myVariableNamedAtRuntime[newName]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no way you can add new variables to the function definition after the function is defined.. However you can always add new properties to the function object defined or it's prototype and you can access them as follows;

```js
function getFromSomewhere(arg1) {

  var newName = arg1 + "_sampleWord_";
  this.getFromSomewhere.varName = newName + "test";
  this.getFromSomewhere.prototype.varName = newName + "best";
  console.log(this.getFromSomewhere.varName);
  console.log(this.getFromSomewhere.prototype.varName);
}

getFromSomewhere("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the variable to the window object:

```
function getFromSomewhere(arg1) {
  var newName = arg1 + "sampleWord";
  window[newName] = [];
}

getFromSomewhere("blip");
console.log(blipsampleWord); // You'd get []
```